# Firestore : how to read efficiently with a large amount of data

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I'm trying to find a good way to read a large amount of data in firestore. Currently , I have 10000 documents in a single collection "movie". These documents are records that contains fields about a movie ( author , title , id). 
My client use a query to read 20 documents randomly with .limit(20) and a user can fire this query as the much as he wants to get new documents. The problem is that an user can ask for example for 1000 documents(movie) and this cost 1000 reads in firestore.

I was thinking if it's possible to reduce the numbers of reads by structuring my collection in a different way with for example 500  subcollections with 20 documents(movies) inside. Like this, I have my documents divided equally and my client can just read 1 subcollection that contains 20 documents. Does this reduce the number of reads to only 1 ?

Comment: I really don't understand what you're trying to accomplish.  This phrase doesn't make any sense to me: *"My new method is to create 500 documents with 20 documents(movies) inside"*

Comment: Thanks for your comment ! I edited my post. I would like to know if by creating subcollections, I could have only 1 read instead of 20.

Comment: Subcollections aren't going to cause fewer document reads.  It doesn't matter where a document is located - a read is a read no matter what.

Comment: What do you exactly mean by "The problem is that an user can ask for 1000 documents and this cost 1000 reads in firestore."? If you use `.limit(20)` in a query, it will only return 20 documents (and the cost will be for 20 docs only).

Comment: I mean a user can fire this query as much as he wants to get new documents. My query gets 20 documents randomly. So I want to know if it's possible to structure my collection in firestore to have a query that cost only 1 read by putting 20 documents in a subcollection. The query should just reads a random subcollection instead of 20 documents

Comment: Not to discuss pricing but isn't it $.06 per 100k reads? So if the user reads 1000 documents (1000 reads) that's $.006? So if 100 users all read 1000 documents, it would be .06. Just trying to understand the issue here... If the *amount* of data is tiny but the reads are what the issue is, then store your data in the Real Time Database. The Blaze plan is $1Gb with no charges for read count.

Answer (score 3):

You're saying:

> My client can read 20 documents randomly using .limit(20) and when a user click on a button 20 new documents are read once again. The problem is that an user can ask for 1000 documents and this cost 1000 reads in firestore.

If you want to limit the user to read at most 20 documents at once, you can do so in the server-side security rules with:

```
// Limit documents per request to 50
allow list: if request.query.limit <= 20
```

Also see the reference documentation on the [query object in security rules](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/rules/rules.firestore.Request#query).

Of course this only limits the number of documents the user can request at one time. They can still perform 50 queries of 20 documents each, and get 1000 documents that way.

Comment: Thanks for your answer ! I wasn't very clear in my first post. What I'm trying to figure out is how to structure my collection to have a query that can get 20 documents randomly with a cost of 1 read. Currently , all my documents are in the same collection.

I use this query to get my 20 documents randomly 
`
    db.collection("movies")
      .where("id", ">", random)
      .limit(20)
      .get()
      });
`

Is it possible to structure firestore and have a query that can get a subcollection with 20 documents inside for the cost of 1 read ?

Comment: There is no way to get multiple documents with the cost of one read. As Doug commented, you seem to have misunderstood how subcollections work. Reading 20 documents from a subcollection still counts as 20 reads. As danh says: the only way to get charged for fewer document reads is to read fewer documents. But you're adding a lot of overhead with such an approach. If this is a cost-saving issue, you might want to consider having a look at the Firebase Realtime Database. This often turns out cheaper for apps where you do many small reads and writes.

Comment: You're right ,  realtime database will be a better solution as my client do only small reads ! I will have a look at this! Thanks !

Answer (score 3):

The only way to have fewer reads is to read fewer docs.  This is true for sub-collection, too. One way to have fewer docs is to fill single docs with more data...

```
// in a single doc
movies: {
  movie_id_a: { title: 'Gone With the Wind', rating: 'G' },
  movie_id_b: { title: 'Casablanca', rating: 'PG' },
  ...
}
```

But this comes at a cost: You'll run into a doc size limit, and you won't be able to use database features associated with keeping logical chunks each in their own doc (like saving a reference to just one movie, or listening to just one movie, etc)

Comment: Thanks ! This is what I want to do to have fewer reads, I guess it's the only solution to reduce my number of reads